# How to enable LDAP extension for PHP in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ldap, ubuntu-16.04, lamp

I am trying to enable `LDAP` for `PHP5.6` on `Ubuntu 16.04`. I have tried the following steps

```
 - sudo apt-get install php5-ldap
 - sudo enmod ldap
 - sudo php5enmod ldap
```

but still I am unable to get my ldap related functions working with PHP

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Yes, `Fatal Error: Call to an undefined function ldap_connect`

Comment: Yes, `Fatal Error: Call to an undefined function ldap_connect`

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install php5-ldap` install successfully ? @baig772

Comment: it said unable to locate php5-ldap but i did `sudo apt-get install php-ldap` and it worked

Comment: Did you restart apache ? `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157203/discussion-between-baig772-and-rathan-naik).

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get install php5.6-ldap to get it for a specific php version then restarted apache and it worked (Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 1):

you need to restart your apache (`systemctl restart apache2`). Apache has its very own single php-process running*. The php-configuration is only reload if apache restarts this process. You can check your active configuration with [phpinfo](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.phpinfo.php)

* this is very simplified and depends on the apache MPM-Module you are using.

Comment: I think this should be in comments sections. It is quite obvious that one always restarts the `apache` whenever apache or php related installation is done

Comment: OT: I'm currently collecting reputation points by answering questions to get the 'comment everywhere'-permission …

Answer (score 1):

latest ubunutu php-ldap was not working I tried installing apt-get install php7.0-ldap which is not working, then I download deb https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/debian-main-amd64/php7.2-ldap_7.2.4-1+b2_amd64.deb.html

wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php-defaults/php-common_49_all.deb

wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-ldap_7.0.29-1+b2_amd64.deb

wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/ucf/ucf_3.0038_all.deb

then..

apt install ./php7.2-common_7.2.4-1+b2_amd64.deb

apt install ./php7.2-ldap_7.2.4-1+b2_amd64.deb
...

once it is installed confirmed by running the

apt-cache pkgnames | grep ldap | grep php

php-symfony-ldap
php7.2-ldap
php-net-ldap2
php-net-ldap3

---

check php enabled modules

:/usr/lib/php/7.2# php -m

ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv

it does not have ldap module..

so copied .so files

:/usr/local/etc/php# cp /usr/lib/php/20170718/ldap.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/

enable apache ldap  " a2enmod ldap"
php-m

now it has ldap module enabled.

[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring

restart apache and checked in info.php.

/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
/etc/init.d/apache2 start

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install php-ldap`

`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

@baig772 answered their own question but they didn't post it as an answer.